# parse complex xml with php in MD array

Tags: php, xml, arrays, parsing

I've been looking around for this, but can't quite seem to find the answer.
I have a fairly complex XML document that I need to parse with PHP. The structure of XML looks like this:

```
<root>

<main id="1"> *some data*

<sub id="1"> *some data*
    <sub id="2"> *some data*
        <sub id="3"> *some data*
            <sub id="4"> *some data* </sub>
            <sub id="5"> *some data* </sub>
        </sub>
    </sub>
</sub>

</main>

</root>
```

It is very important to parse this document into a multidimensional array with same structure.

There is one problem, however. There is no way of knowing how many sub-levels there are inside of a first  tag, if any at all. This document is dynamically created by another system, and the sub-structure of each *main* tag is different.
I tried using SimpleXMLElement, but it only parsed the first level, i.e. the data between the *main* tag and the first *sub* tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string):

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
```

Doesn't matter how many levels you have or what the structure is.. so long as it's valid you'll get an object you can work with.

Comment: Mike, thank you for your answer and help, but that just don't cut it. Tried that already, but like I said, the output isn't valid, i.e. the parser does not grab the data from deeper structures.

Comment: <?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
<S id="1">

<sub_S id="1">
data data data

<sub_S id="2">
data data data

<sub_S id="3"> 
data data data

<sub_S id="4">
data data data

</sub_S></sub_S></sub_S></sub_S>

<sub_S id="main"> 
data data data
</sub_S>

</S>
</document>